# event hub to log entry when new file arrives

Tags: azure, events, azure-eventhub

can anyone help me understand how to write message to the Event Hub and log entry when new file arrives into the server.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question a bit? What SDK are you coding with? Where is your app deployed? What do you mean by ' when new file arrives'?

Comment: @ Serkant-Thanks for the response. My only basic query at the initial level is i'm using the logic App -"Send event" Connector to send a event entry or any log to the event hub - the logic app that is getting success should log a entry of that event into event hub - where it will appear in event hub? Secondquestion - this logic app contains a first connector -"When a SFTP-SSH for when file added or modified by properties" and the next step is the send event when a new file is dropped into the sftp server into particular location the LA gets triggered and passes it to next connector ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the Logic App's Event Hubs action. Basically, you can add an Event Hubs action to send an event to your eventhub at any position of you Logic Apps workflow. See following doc for step by step guide.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azure-event-hubs#add-event-hubs-action

You probably know SFTP connector however adding the do link here in case you need it -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sftp

Comment: Ok thanks for that but ok on the logic App end in the event hub when the event is being sent to the hib where its getting stored?

Comment: Requesting for answers for the above

Comment: Think Event Hubs as a commit log. Events are persisted at the service so consumer clients can read them when they are available.

Comment: really didnt understand

Comment: Which part? I will answer with more details if you can point which part you didn’t understand.

Comment: Simple question: How to view event hub messages which receives from the "Send event" Connector being used by Logic App? Mail Id: anirudhb488@gmail.com

Comment: Do you want to view them for testing purpose or as part of your production data pipeline? If for testing purpose then SBExplorer will be handy - https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer

Comment: first testing & then for production usage thanks where do i download it from is it from above link?

Comment: I have installed event hub explorer on windows to view messages in event hub, using the VS exntensions can you quickly help to navigate through the screen am struck after installation.

Comment: @ Serkant thanks for all the help you have taken time on commenting for each ask. But the above link seems to be with Service bus explorer to view something for service bus But My requirement was for Event hub messages to be viewed - and that Now I am done using the event hub explorer using the VS installer Online Thanks.

Comment: SBExplorer works for both Service Bus and Event Hubs. Let me know if you hit any issues.

Comment: Thanks I have already completed installation, but few points taken from your end too thanks fully i couldn't understand so explored from google,

Comment: can you help me on how can we send dynamically the currentt date & time in service bus by passing it in JSON message I am created?

Comment: Each EventData has EnqueuedDateTime stamped on the broker. Why do you need to stamp it on the client side? It sounds redundant.

Comment: I have myself worked on it and written code. now i am able to receive dynamci date and timefor each file dropped in sftp server accroding to the parameters